# Cocos2D camera movement?

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, box2d, box2d-iphone

What is the best way I center the screen to follow the character? Should I use `CCCamera` or just move the background around?

I am new to cocos2d so please show me exact code.

BTW: I am also using box2d in this project.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this...

```
[self runAction:[CCFollow actionWithTarget:(your hero) worldBoundary:CGRectMake(0,0,1050,350)]];
```

It will follow your character (your hero).

Answer (score 1):

Hey there,
You have always to choose between the best way and the best way in your situation. A problem has multiple ways how you can solve it. So I can just tell you how I did it.

A few weeks ago I released my first game. (If you are interested check it out: [Birdy!](http://www.fidelisfactory.ch/?page_id=404)) I also used Cocos2d and had the same problem like you. The player should always be in the center of the screen. I've choosen the way to move the background. I added 2 things to the GameScene: The background and the bird. And I set the background as the bird's delegate. So as soon as the bird performs a jump for example, the background is moved in the opposite direction.

I think for my situation it was the best method. But I can't talk about `CCCamera` because I never did anything with that class...

I hope I could help you a little bit. But it's always a bit difficult to find the right way. So you should also think about things you will optionally add in the future. So perhaps my way does not fit your requirements...

I hope also my english is understandable...

Sandro Meier

Comment: Thank you! I pretty much figured it out.